# CFL Pumping Lemma L = {a^n b^m c^k d^k | n>m}

Tags: context-free-grammar, dfa, formal-languages, context-free-language, pumping-lemma

I have some troubles solving this exercise with context free pumping lemma. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language can be shown not to be regular using the pumping lemma for regular languages. It is context free and this is a grammar for it:

```
S -> LR
L -> a | aL | aLb
R -> e | cRd
```

Basically, recognize the a/b part is totally separate from the c/d part and concatenate grammars for each of the two.